# testthat (& Catch) complains in R CMD check that xml2 library is missing

Tags: c++, r, testthat, catch2

I am using testthat to test my R package (https://github.com/beerda/hexmatrix). Recently, I started C++ testing: I have executed `testthat::use_catch()`, which should setup the package for unit testing with C++ Catch, and then I wrote some tests. The tests run correctly if executed by `devtools::test()`. However, if I try to run `R CMD check` or `devtools::check()`, I get the following error message:

```
    Running ‘testthat.R’ (1.8s)
   Running the tests in ‘tests/testthat.R’ failed.
   Last 13 lines of output:
     > test_check("hexmatrix")
     ── Error (test-cpp.R:1:1): (code run outside of `test_that()`) ─────────────────
     Error: The xml2 package must be installed in order to use `run_cpp_tests()`
     ℹ Do you need to run `install.packages('xml2')`?
     Backtrace:
         █
      1. └─testthat::run_cpp_tests("hexmatrix") test-cpp.R:1:0
      2.   └─testthat:::check_installed("xml2", "run_cpp_tests()")
     
     ══ testthat results  ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
     Error (test-cpp.R:1:1): (code run outside of `test_that()`)
     
     [ FAIL 1 | WARN 0 | SKIP 0 | PASS 909 ]
     Error: Test failures
     Execution halted
```

The xml2 package is installed, rlang::check_installed("xml2") returns TRUE.

Not sure if it is somehow connected: when I try to execute manually the command `run_cpp_tests("hexmatrix")`, I get the following error:

```
Error in read_xml.raw(charToRaw(enc2utf8(x)), "UTF-8", ..., as_html = as_html,  : 
  XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document [64]
```

Does please anybody have the idea what is going wrong? Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems solved by adding `xml2` into `Suggests` section of the `DESCRIPTION` file of the package.

Answer (score 0):

That should not be a testthat dependency, due to that you don't use explicitly the library xml2 ?